# Setting values of enumerations, and parsing string to get an enum

Tags: java, enumeration

My enum is like this currently:

```
public enum Manufacturers {
  Honda,
  GM,
  Toyota,
  Ferrari
}
```

I need to create a Hashmap so I plan on doing this, is this correct?

```
Manufacturers mfg = Manufacturers.Honda;

mfg.ordinal()  // save as key
```

i.e. I will store the key using the `enumInstance.ordinal()`

Also, I need to be able to parse a string which will be the ordinal value of the enumeration, and get an enum back:

```
Manufacturers mfg = Manufacturers.valueOf(mfgOrdinalValueAsString);
```

The above gave me an error (the string was "1").  Is this the correct way?  I guess I should have a try/catch in there right?

Answer (score 2):

The `.valueOf` would actually be expecting the String "GM" (for 1).

As for storing your enum values in a map, use `EnumMap` which is designed specifically for this - and will be fast at it, too.

If you really wanted to reference a value by its ordinal, use something like `Manufacturers.values()[1]`.

Comment: I can't seem to set the ordinal value explicitly either, I tried:  GM("5"), Toyota("6")

Comment: No, you can't set them - the ordinals will match the order that the values are declared in within the enum.

Comment: If for some reason you need a different `int` number associated with each element of the enum (other than its automatically assigned ordinal), you can always add it as an attribute to the enum, together with getters

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion: better use `name()` to get the *name* of the enum as a `String`, and whenever you need to get back the original `Enum` from it, use the `valueOf()` method - since `valueOf()` expects the *name*, not the ordinal, as a parameter. For example:

```
enum Example {ONE, TWO};

String name = Example.ONE.name();
Example e = Example.valueOf(Example.class, name);  // e has value ONE
```

If you definitely need to use the ordinal, the `ordinal()` method will return an index which you can use to retrieve the respective `Enum` from the array returned by the `values()` method. Like this:

```
int ordinal = Example.ONE.ordinal();
Example e = Example.values()[ordinal];  // e has value ONE
```

As has already been pointed out, consider using [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html), as stated in the documentation, it is

> A specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys. All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created. Enum maps are represented internally as arrays. This representation is extremely compact and efficient.

**EDIT**

If you need to associate a different code to each element of the enum (other than its automatically assigned ordinal), you can always add it as an attribute to the enum, together with getters and setters, like this:

```
public enum Manufacturers {

    Honda(10),
    GM(20),
    Toyota(30),
    Ferrari(40);

    private int code;

    Manufacturers(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

For example:

```
Manufacturers m = Manufacturers.Honda;
System.out.println(m.getCode()); // prints 10
m.setCode(100);
System.out.println(m.getCode()); // prints 100
```

Just be aware that you won't be able to reconstruct an `Enum` object from the `code` attribute, since that was defined by the programmer.

Comment: so you can only cast using the name, not the ordinal value?

Comment: That's right, for retrieving the enum using only the ordinal, use `values()`. I updated my answer with code examples.